# What is immediate="true" translated into html

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

I am using the `apex:inputField` to capture the values and and `required="true"` to set some of the fields mandatory. However, for some buttons like cancel, I don't want it to check the required fields. If I am using `apex:commandButton` I can use `immediate="true"` to resolve this. However, since there are many things `apex:commandButton` can't do I am using standard html and javascript. I find it hard to translate `immediate="true"` as I saw no difference in the html when debugging. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this help? http://blog.jerryorr.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html

Comment: In html-5 the formnovalidate=true is the equivalent http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formnovalidate.asp

Comment: @Eric Thank you for the response. I haven't tried this thoroughly but I guess there is some difference. formNoValidate attribute is actually working on the client side and in my case, the page actually reloads before it populates error. So I am guessing it is happening at server side.

Comment: With pictures: [JSF and the “immediate” Attribute – Command Components](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/01/jsf-and-immediate-attribute-command.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct translation for the immediate attribute, because it only affects server-side validation. In essence, this attribute is evaluated early in the Visualforce transaction lifecycle, before any user-defined code can execute.

While there is a concept of client-side validation in html 5, there's no analogous concept in html 5 for server-side validation, because that's outside the scope of the language definition, and left to the developers of server-side execution, such as salesforce, to define those mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments and @sfdcfox's answer, the "immediate" attribute affects server logic, and has no direct equivalent in HTML.

However, both actionFunction and commandButton support immediate=true. Have you tried calling an actionFunction (rather than just submitting the form) when you want the "immediate=true" support? Alternatively simulating a click event on a hidden commandButton? Either of those should have the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am actually using actionFunction. That will save me some time in implementing this. One thing I am concerned is whether we need to go to server side to verify the mandatory fields though. However, it doesn't seem to be too bad.